# What does “uninterpenetratingly” mean?

Tags: meaning, literature

I was looking up the longest words in certain works of fiction when I discovered this monstrosity: ***uninterpenetratingly***. It is used in Chapter 108 of *[Moby Dick](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/2701-h/2701-h.htm)* as follows:

> How dost thou know that some entire, living, thinking thing may not be invisibly and uninterpenetratingly standing precisely where thou now standest; aye, and standing there in thy spite?

However I am still unsure as to the meaning of this word, as I could not find it in any dictionaries. Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: Decompose into roots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/interpenetrate) defines **interpenetrate** as:

> verb
>
> 1. to penetrate (something) thoroughly; pervade
> 2. to penetrate each other or one another mutually

Under Derived Forms is listed:

> interˈpenetratively  adverb

So uninterpenetratingly means, "not in a thoroughly penetrating or pervasive way."

To stand invisible and uninterpenetratingly is to stand in a way that can not be seen or felt because it has no detectable effect on you.